# One sided limits (1)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Does these limits exists:

> $$1)\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$$
>   $$2)\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$$
>   $$3)\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$$

$$1)\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}= \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})= " \frac {1}{0^+}+\frac {1}{(0^+)^3}"= "\infty+ \infty"=+\infty$$

No the limit for $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$ does not exist.
$$2)\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}= \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})= " \frac {1}{0^-}+\frac {1}{(0^-)^3}"= "-\infty- \infty"=-\infty$$
No the limit for $\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}$ does not exist.
$$3)\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})= " 0 + 0"= 0$$

Yes, there is a limit for $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}=0$

My questions are:Is this correct what I did?Or do I have to do more to prove the existence of the limit than to calculate them?

Comment: What does it mean that the limit exists? See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187368/limit-of-a-sequence-1n-instead-1/187386#187386).

Comment: I know that if the two limits from the two sides for an $x_0$ exists the limit for this $x_0$ exists.in the orginal problem there was asked for $\lim_{x \to x_0^-}$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0^+}$ so I assumed that "$x_0 = 0$".If the limit exists there is a function which converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are doing is in essence, correct. You could provide a more formal proof if you wished. For example, you can determine that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}=0$ by various logical arguments, including the kind you just presented.

Then from definition, for an arbitrarily large $E=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, there exists $\delta$ such that $\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}-0<\epsilon$ for $x-0<\delta$. Taking the reciprocal on both sides of the inequality, we get that
$\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}=E$  for all $x<\delta$. Thus, the function can be made arbitrarily large and thus we have proved that a limit does not exist.

Comment: That would have been my next question, if I have to use the (ε, δ)-definition.

Comment: So I don't even have to regard a particular $x_0^+$ and $x_0^-$ when we can say that there is an $x<\delta$ with this "the function can be made arbitrarily large"?

Comment: No, we are still taking limit towards $0^+$
In this case, it is $x-x_0<\delta$ where $x_0$ is $0$ and $\delta>0$

Comment: But where is the differene between $0^+$ and $0^-$ by doing $x-x_0<\delta => x-0^-<\delta <=> \delta>0 $ isn't it the same as for $0^+$?

Comment: No, for $0^-$ we would have $0-x<\delta$, and $\delta>0$

Answer (score 0):

In the last case you have to remember that $0$ doesn't belong to the domain of definition. So the function is even continuous. After that you can just calculate the answer.